# O que "amor é assim" significa?

Tags: significado-em-contexto

Nas muitos canções tem colocação de palavras «amor é assim». Por exemplo:

> O nosso amor vai ser assim,
>
> Eu pra você, você pra mim.
>
> *(Tom Jobim — O nosso amor)*

O que esta colocação de palavras significa? Significa "the love is the same as before" ou tem outra significado?

Comment: A palavra "assim" tem alguns significados. Nesse caso, o significado é "like this", apenas que "assim" não é informal. A canção diz algo como."our love will be like this, me for you, and you for me.".

Comment: Welcome to Portuguese SE, Sauron! What are your thoughts? The dictionaries [suggest](https://www.wordreference.com/pten/assim) "this way", "like this", "so", etc.

Comment: Your example does not contain the phrase you are asking about. [correction: em muitas canções]

Comment: Eu ouviu pelo penos 4 canções com «amor é assim» em formas diferentes. Agora eu não conseguia lembrar suas nomes.